# CMake Error at cocos2d/cmake/Modules/CocosConfigDepend.cmake:94 (endmacro): Flow control statements are not properly nested

Tags: cmake, cocos2d-x, xcode12, cmake-modules, xcode12.5

Hey I'm a newbie cocos 2d x developer, I'm just trying to get a "Hello World" project created in XCode for iOS.  From the terminal I'm using the command

```
cmake ../.. -GXcode -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=iphoneos
```

I keep getting these two errors and the xcode project file does not generate.

```
CMake Error at cocos2d/cmake/Modules/CocosConfigDepend.cmake:94 (endmacro):
  Flow control statements are not properly nested.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cocos2d/cmake/Modules/CocosBuildSet.cmake:43 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:42 (include)
```

What am I doing wrong?

see attached screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIiNC.jpg

System Specs:

```
MacOS Big Sur 11.4 (Virtual Machine via VMware)
cocos2d-x-4.0
cocos Console 2.3
Xcode 12.5.1
Python 2.7.16
cmake 3.21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

CMake 3.14+
Xcode 10+
Visual Studio 2019
Android Studio 3.4+，NDK r19c+

Need https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake

Try this

```
enter code here
$mkdir build_ios
$cd build_ios
$cmake .. -GXcode -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../ios.toolchain.cmake -DENABLE_ARC=FALSE
$open test.xcodeproj
```

The default is iOS device project, and platform parameters such as
os.toolchain.cmake support -DPLATFORM=SIMULATOR64 need to be added when adjusting to simulator. Please refer to its documentation